# Getting SSL related error against my request to Ejabberd

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, erlang, ejabberd

Following is the code snippet where i open a socket to write APNS notifications on:

```
 get_socket()->
 %%Options
  Options = [{certfile, ?Cert}, {keyfile, ?Key}, {mode, binary}],
  %%ssl connection
  ssl:connect(?Address, ?Port, Options, infinity)
.

 close_socket(Socket)->
 ssl:close(Socket).
```

I am getting the following crash in my **ejabberd.log** file

```
2015-06-05 12:33:17.112 [error] <0.3134.0> gen_fsm <0.3134.0> in state certify terminated with reason: no function clause matching ssl_cipher:hash_algorithm(239) line 1174

2015-06-05 12:33:17.113 [error] <0.3134.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.3134.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching ssl_cipher:hash_algorithm(239) line 1174 in gen_fsm:terminate/7 line 622

2015-06-05 12:33:17.113 [error] <0.99.0> Supervisor tls_connection_sup had child undefined started with {tls_connection,start_link,undefined} at <0.3134.0> exit with reason no function clause matching ssl_cipher:hash_algorithm(239) line 1174 in context child_terminated

2015-06-05 12:33:17.113 [error] <0.3133.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.3133.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{function_clause,[{ssl_cipher,hash_algorithm,"Ã¯",[{file,"ssl_cipher.erl"},{line,1174}]},{ssl_handshake,'-decode_handshake/3-blc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,898}]},{ssl_handshake,'-deode_handshake/3-blc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,899}]},{ssl_handshake,decode_handshake,3,[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,898}]},{tls_handshake,get_tls_handshake_aux,3,[{file,"tls_handshake.erl"},{line,153}]},{tls_connection,next_state,4,[{file,"tls_connection.erl"},{line,454}]},...]},...} in gen_fsm:sync_send_all_state_event/3 line 240

2015-06-05 12:33:17.113 [error] <0.377.0> Supervisor ejabberd_http_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_http,start_link,undefined} at <0.3133.0> exit with reason {{function_clause,[{ssl_cipher,hash_algorithm,"Ã¯",[{file,"ssl_cipher.erl"},{line,1174}]},{ssl_handshake,'-decode_handshake/3-blc$^0/1-0-',1,[file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,898}]},{ssl_handshake,'-decode_handshake/3-blc$^0/1-0-',1,[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,899}]},{ssl_handshake,decode_handshake,3,[{file,"ssl_handshake.erl"},{line,898}]},{tls_handshake,get_tls_handshake_aux,3,[{file,"tls_handshake.erl"},{line,153}]},{tls_connection,next_state,4,[{file,"tls_connection.erl"},{line,454}]},...]},...} in context child_terminated

2015-06-05 12:33:17.372 [debug] <0.3074.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:343 Received XML on stream = <<"<iq type=\"get\" to=\"+919333333333@devlab\" id=\"vCard-Temp2C753D87-6F56-48D5-B3CF-09C1B1DF46F7\"><vCard xmlns=\"vcard-temp\"/></iq>">>

2015-06-05 12:33:17.372 [debug] <0.3074.0>@shaper:update:117 State: {maxrate,1000,623.3758292140764,1433496796970483}, Size=125
M=90.80183440963172, I=402.231
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Which version of Erlang are you using?

Comment: Got same problem today. Must be Apple introduced some change on their servers.

Comment: also seeing this issue as of a couple days ago. Restarting my servers fixed production but debug tokens still aren't working.

Comment: @TrespassersW  I am gettin this:
** When State == hello
**      Data  == [{data,
                      [{"StateData",{state,client, {#Ref<0.0.0.83>,<0.47.0>},                                 gen_tcp,tls_connection,tcp,tcp_closed,tcp_error,"gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",2195,    and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can go about it. I work on the sandbox environment and after a bit of patching, i could make it work.

Follow the patching done here:

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2015-June/084868.html

You would be required to make changes in ssl_cipher.erl and ssl_handshake.erl files. These 2 files are a part of the Erlang OTP you are using and not the ejabberd.

In my case the path is:

/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ssl-5.3.2/src

Having compiled these 2 erls, you would have to move the beams to /usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/ssl-5.3.2/ebin.

Restart Ejabberd. And check if Push notifications work.
Normally, they should.

Comment: Thanks man! It helped. I could get those on my setup for now.
Apple Inc. should think of the developers before making encryption changes like these. Untracable impact. :/